# NullPointerException on CustomContact insert

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

**The code:**

```
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        // Create raw contact
        Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "testaccount");
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "nl.my.project.account");
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, "username"); 
        operationList.add(builder.build());

        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "name"); 
        operationList.add(builder.build());

        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.nl.my.project.profile");
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, "username");
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "Profile");
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "View profile");
        operationList.add(builder.build());

        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**contacts.xml:**

```
<ContactsSource xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ContactsDataKind
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.nl.my.project.profile"
        android:summaryColumn="data2"
        android:detailColumn="data3"
        android:detailSocialSummary="true" />
</ContactsSource>
```

**Logcat:**

```
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223): Writing exception to parcel
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223):     at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.insertData(ContactsProvider2.java:2574)
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223):     at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.insertInTransaction(ContactsProvider2.java:2422)
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223):     at com.android.providers.contacts.SQLiteContentProvider.insert(SQLiteContentProvider.java:106)
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223):     at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.insert(ContactsProvider2.java:2238)
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223):     at android.content.ContentProviderOperation.apply(ContentProviderOperation.java:214)
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223):     at com.android.providers.contacts.SQLiteContentProvider.applyBatch(SQLiteContentProvider.java:216)
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223):     at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.applyBatch(ContactsProvider2.java:2272)
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:193)
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:173)
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
09-23 09:09:23.981: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(223):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing:

```
Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
```

To:

```
Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

Seems to fix the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

try working like this

ArrayList ops = new ArrayList();
                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                            .build());